# I want to store values of button click in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a Tic tac toe game in Javascript, I have made this game in `C++` but now I want to implement it in Javascript, but the problem with the javascript is that I cannot store the previous value in an array. Like I am using buttons and if button is clicked for the first user it should store the button value in an array for each time user clicks, so that at last I can make conclusion and declare the winner.

Here is the [link for the code](http://jsfiddle.net/atulverma/zhNfB/1).

Comment: Move your array initialization outside the click handler. check your logic as well for storing values for 2 users in 2 separate arrays.

Comment: include your code in question

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/polaki_2005/WCVrQ/

Answer (score 0):

Add code in your question so that it easier for everyone. Now as per your fiddle, these are the following corrections, on every function call you are making a new array

Check the following updated code

```
<script>
 var array= new Array();   // move array out of function as 
                          //you want to store in array on every click
function myFunction(name,n)
{


 array[n]=name;

    if(n%2==0)
    {
    array[n]='x';   
    }
    else
    {
        array[n]='o' // fix spellling
        check1();
    }

        function check1()
        {   
         if(array[0] && array[1] && array[2] == 'x')
           alert("congrats");

        }        

}</script>
```